# How to emulate/test bluetooth chat?

Tags: java, android, bluetooth

http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/BluetoothChat/index.html

As you know, the emulator does not have bluetooth support. My question is: is there any workaround to test the bluetooth chat from the sample?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation states there is no Bluetooth support for the emulator. And you really should just test with devices if you have access to them.

I have never tried this, but I have read over before just finding a spare device. So if you are really stuck with just the emulator you can give this a shot. It's not a guarantee but it's something to look into.

https://github.com/cheng81/Android-Bluetooth-Simulator

Last I checked it supports:

- switch on/off the "radio"
- discovery devices (only other android emulators)
- creating bluetooth services
- connecting to bluetooth
  services

Comment: Should I suppose that at least there's need that the PC has bluetooth to work with a "real" phone?

Comment: I'm confused what you mean. The custom library I linked I don't believe you need bluetooth, it is hacked up to use TCP communication instead, while having a similar setup to the Android Bluetooth API

Answer (score 0):

You probably have to test/debug with real devices - IMHO there's no way to get bluetooth working on the emulator, not even a workaround